# Differential equations: difference between first order DE and separable variable DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, definition

The difference between the definition offirst order DE and separable variable DE seem very near for me, so does separable variables DE are a special case of first order DE, if not is there some differential equation which obey both definitions, or they are totally opposite things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All separable differential equations are first order differential equations, but not all first order differential equations are separable.

Comment: But y'=exp(y)*5x is separable, but by definition(in my textbook) a 1st order DE is definied as y'=a(x)y+b(x), here b(x)=0, but can a(x)= 5x* exp(y)? Isn't the definition. Thank you

Comment: No, that's the definition of a first order **linear** DE.  First order just means that the first derivative appears in the equation but no higher derivative.

Comment: Ok,so first order linear equations and separable variables differential equations,arn't the same things at all?

Comment: Correct.  There are first order linear equations that are not separable, and separable equations that are not linear, and equations that are both, and equations that are neither.